# How do I concatenate arrays of aliases in Perl?

Tags: arrays, perl, alias

How do you concatenate arrays of aliases in Perl such that the resulting array also contains aliases?

The solution that I came up with is:

```
my ($x, $y, $z) = 1 .. 3;

my $a1 = sub {\@_}->($x);

my $a2 = sub {\@_}->($y, $z);

my $a3 = sub {\@_}->(@$a1, @$a2);

say "@$a3";  # 1 2 3

$_++ for $x, $y, $z;

say "@$a3";  # 2 3 4
```

What I am not crazy about is that to create `$a3` I have to completely unpack `$a1` and `$a2`.  For short arrays this isn't a problem, but as the data grows larger, it means that all array operations on aliased arrays are `O(n)`, including traditionally `O(1)` operations like `push` or `unshift`.

`Data::Alias` could help, but it doesn't work with the latest versions of Perl.  `Array::RefElem` contains wrappers around the api primitives `av_store` and `av_push` which can be used to implement this functionality.  So something like this could work:

```
sub alias_push (\@@) {
    if (eval {require Array::RefElem}) {
       &Array::RefElem::av_push($_[0], $_) for @_[1 .. $#_]
    } else {
       $_[0] = sub {\@_}->(@{$_[0]}, @_[1 .. $#_])
    }
}
```

I am interested to know if there are any other ways.  Particularly if there are any other ways using only the core modules.

Comment: I think "fix Data::Aliases" might be the best (although perhaps not the fastest) way to go. :)

Comment: @Ether => Any idea how deep the incompatibilities run?

Comment: @Eric: no, although I suspect someone just needs to find a tuit to port it to use the 5.12 API bindings.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by unpack, but that `(@$a1,@$a2)` isn't doing anything beyond what you actually need to build a new array...Not sure what you mean about O(n) operations on the array of aliases: it's just an array, and push, unshift, etc work normally.

Comment: @ysth => that's true for the first example I gave, but not the second.  In the definition of `alias_push`, the pure perl way of doing it (at least that I came up with) requires expanding the original array in a subroutine's argument list along with the new items, and then the sub creates a new array ref that is installed in the old ones spot, simply doing `push @{$_[0]}, @_[1..$#_];` won't insert aliases, it will insert the values.

Comment: Ah, I didn't get that from "all array operations on aliased arrays...push or unshift".

Answer (score 1):

Is this one of the cases where you might want a linked list in Perl? [Steve Lembark has a talk](http://www.slideshare.net/lembark/perly-linked-lists) about the various cases where people should reconsider rolling and unrolling arrays.

I'm curious why you have to do things this way though. Not that I suspect anything odd; I'm just curious about the problem.

Comment: the linked list might be a good solution, it nicely sidesteps the `O(n)` issues.  the application that I have in mind is to simulate Haskell like lazy behavior in Perl (mainly just because I think I can :), I'd like to eventually write something like this in Perl: `fibs = 0 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs)` and part of that is managing argument lists that may contain values that have not been defined yet (but will be by the time they are needed)

Comment: Oh, in that case, wait a year and use Perl 6. Lazy lists are one of the most attractive features for me. :)

Comment: @Eric, @brian, or maybe Perl 5.1x? (where x > 2 and x || 2)